# Javascript charCodeAt not reading correct codes

Tags: javascript, unicode, processing

I was trying to host a code of mine from Khan Academy on my own website.
The processing code works alright on Khan Academy. But while hosting it I am facing some issues.

The problem is - Khan Academy's processing is able to read unicode value of certain characters correctly, but when I do the same offline from the browser it gets incorrectly shown.

I think it has to do with the charCodeAt function not working correctly.

Here's my code :-

```
var test = "Ĭ";
println(test);
println(test.charCodeAt(0));
```

On Khan Academy the unicode is correctly printed as 300. Wherease my browser prints it as 196. Whats more the string is interpreted as 2 characters instead of 1 from the browser. It's size is shown as 2.

How to make the charCodeAt to work correctly.

Please note that I am making use of Processing JS and here is the code I am making use of to host a Processing Canvas :-

```
var sketchProc=function(processingInstance){ with (processingInstance)   {
size(400, 400); 
frameRate(60);



var test = "Ĭ";
var n = test.codePointAt(0);

println(n);

println(String.fromCharCode(300));
println(test.length);

}};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser? `"Ĭ".length` and `"Ĭ".charCodeAt(0)` gives me `1` and `300` in Chrome.

Comment: yaa it works perfectly

Comment: Thing is, I am using processing JS. I am making use of the version :-
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js

Comment: I depends on Content-Type response
it have to be charset="UTF-8" (or other unicode encoding)

Comment: I m not sure which version Khan Academy uses. I tried to use a few different versions. But the link to the processing version was taken from Khan Academy, where it is working correctly.

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin can you explain how I can make it UTF-16 .

Comment: just output script/page with:
header: `ContentType: text/javascript; charset="UTF-16"` or `ContentType: text/html; charset="UTF-16"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of AlexandrKapustin, I was able to resolve the problem.

I added the following meta tag to the html file hosting the Processing script :-

```
<meta charset="utf-16">
```